# How to manually set a return value to a subquery with multiple results

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a subquery which can return multiple results if a customer has duplicated sales codes.

I currently `LIMIT 1` to just return the most recent but ... Is there away to return NULL or "DUPLICATE" if `RESULT > 1`?

I am using this field to overwrite a field which already has a default - therefore, I would just prefer to use the default or raise an alert for rectification.

Comment: *if a customer has duplicated sales codes.* This is practically equal to "My data is inconsistent, but I don't want to purify my data and do something to prevent this in future". It's bad... It is necessary to treat the disease and not its symptoms. I'd recommend you: 1) remove duplicates; 2) create unique index which prevents duplicates.

Comment: Did you read the OP - "I would just prefer to use the default or raise an alert for rectification."

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, add a select case to your subquery

```
select (select case when (select count(*) from subquery) >1 then 'duplicate' else 'not duplicate' end)
```

Though I'm not sure if I would recommend that, but there is one method.